# Starting tomcat v8.5 server at localhost has encounterd a problem

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, tomcat8

Starting tomcat v8.5 server at localhost has encounterd a problem

How to solve with command prompt?

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with complete error log in text format

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the previous service running on the specific Port number is stopped, check the dependencies are properly added for it or not and finally try changing the PortNumber give for it! and if still, the problem is unsolved please provide some more details regarding error! Thank u! Happy learning!

Comment: we have tried all the possible answers we can..... we have also tried changing port numbers ,restarted the server, deleted the server and again added it but it was  all waste of time and we posted here the Actual server error.

Comment: Can you add some details to it? I mean can u add the actual code which u trying to run!